# Fullcalendar 4 month display with day number only

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to create a view, where you display the whole month without the events rows at all?

Basically I want to have a grid with big day number only per cell ( and selecting a date working ).

example image: https://i.ibb.co/9vK2pxn/Selection-002.png

Comment: Did you try `events:[]`?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work I am afraid.

Comment: Oh that's strange. When I worked on it, I used to get empty array from the server and that would be assigned to events (fullCalendar) and the calendar would be with empty cells.

Comment: do you remember what view were you using, i am afraid i am just using a wrong one and I can't find the docs with all available views. I am currently trying with defaultView: 'dayGridWeek',

Comment: I did test out the monthView. Checkout their examples, it should downloadable zip file which will give you all kinds of views available .

Comment: sounds like you really want a datepicker control rather than a calendar app?

Comment: yea I don't really need the full potential of full calendar for this specific case. but most of the libs i could google are input date pickers and not standalone calendars. If you have an example of some library that is being maintained still I would appreciate it. Also I use full calendar for other pages where I use the events system they provide

Comment: jQueryUI's datepicker can be used standalone (i.e. not attached to an input element). I don't personally know of any others but I wouldn't be surprised if there are a few more